# Ldap Authentication not working in Kong Api Gateway

Tags: authentication, ldap, kong

I'm trying to setup the LDAP Authentication in Kong Gateway but i'm getting always : "message":"Invalid authentication credentials"

I'm using an online LDAP test server https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

This server is accessible by ***ldapsearch*** command but not with kong. I'm following all the steps mentioned in the documentation but still couldn't make it work.

I'm using the 2.5.0 version of Kong.

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Install kong using docker image with postgres DB
2. Create service and route
3. Check that route is accessible without authentification
4. Setup LDAP Authentication:

> curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/routes/{ROUTE}/plugins \ --data "name=ldap-auth" \ --data "config.hide_credentials=true" \ --data
> "config.ldap_host= ldap.forumsys.com" \ --data "config.ldap_port=389"
> \ --data "config.start_tls=false" \ --data "config.ldaps=false" 
> --data "config.base_dn=dc=example,dc=com" \ --data "config.verify_ldap_host=false" \ --data "config.attribute=cn" 
> --data "config.cache_ttl=60" \ --data "config.header_type=ldap"

5. Try to access route using the credentials : euler:password (for exemple, you can see in the logs of ldapsearch i attached that this credentials are accessible)

> ```
> curl -i -X GET --url http://localhost:8000/ --header 'Host: example.com' -H 'Authorization: ldap ZXVsZXI6cGFzc3dvcmQ='
>
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> Date: Wed, 21 Jul 2021 09:16:17 GMT
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 52
> X-Kong-Response-Latency: 178
> Server: kong/2.5.0
>
> {
> "message":"Invalid authentication credentials"
> }
> ```